# Why are wind on Earth and wind in space different?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum, flow

When I cut a hole in the window, the outside wind will be sucked or spilled into my room. But when I do the same thing on a spaceship in space, everything inside the ship is sucked out with a very strong force of attraction, which is the exact opposite of the results I get when I do that on the spaceship. The earth. That is, the wind in space does not enter the ship, but on the contrary, it sucks the objects in the ship out into space. So why is there such a difference?
**Please help me edit what you think should be fixed.**

Answer (score 1):

*Sucking* isn't real; *blowing* is. (As explained in the discussion of misconception 4 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyD8VIK032o), vacua don't suck.) To be more precise, matter in high-pressure regions is thereby pushed to where there is lower pressure. (This is analogous to the fact that *cold* isn't real; *heat* is, but it moves from warmer regions to cooler ones.) In your first experiment, air pressure is atypically high just outside the window because of the wind; in your second, the pressure inside the spaceship, high enough for astronauts to breathe, is far higher than that outside in space, which is almost a perfect vacuum.